# SSIS to Snowflake connection

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Has anybody had success connecting to Snowflake from SSIS? If so can you please share how to create the ODBC data source in detail and then how to create the connection in SSIS. Please help.

I am trying to create the ODBC data source using the Snowflake 32bit ODBC driver, but it is not working. Then I need to use this ODBC connection in SSIS to fetch the data from Snowflake.

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting creating the Snowflake ODBC data source?